# How to bind database using LIST?

Tags: asp.net, sql, radtreeview, radtreelist

Hi iam try to Get Database data and showed in RadTreeview,
here i got one sample,that sample like default sample,every Root and Child has to be enter manually,
but i want bind from database,values are filled automatically(root/child)

i will show that example code,

```
List<SiteDataItem> siteData = new List<SiteDataItem>();

        siteData.Add(new SiteDataItem(1, 0, "Products"));
        siteData.Add(new SiteDataItem(2, 1, "RadControls for ASP.NET Ajax"));
        siteData.Add(new SiteDataItem(3, 1, "RadControls for Silverlight"));
        siteData.Add(new SiteDataItem(4, 2, "RadGrid"));
        siteData.Add(new SiteDataItem(5, 2, "RadScheduler"));
        siteData.Add(new SiteDataItem(6, 2, "RadEditor"));
        siteData.Add(new SiteDataItem(7, 3, "RadGrid"));
        siteData.Add(new SiteDataItem(8, 3, "RadMenu"));
        siteData.Add(new SiteDataItem(9, 3, "RadEditor"));

       RadTreeView1 .DataTextField = "Text";
       RadTreeView1.DataFieldID = "ID";
       RadTreeView1.DataFieldParentID = "ParentID";
       RadTreeView1.DataSource = siteData;
       RadTreeView1.DataBind();
```

Please help me to do as i want

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    List<TestModels> models = new List<TestModels>();

    models.Add(new TestModels() { ID = 1, ParentID = null, Text = "a1" });
    models.Add(new TestModels() { ID = 2, ParentID = 1, Text = "a2" });
    models.Add(new TestModels() { ID = 3, ParentID = 2, Text = "a3" });
    models.Add(new TestModels() { ID = 4, ParentID = null, Text = "a4" });
    models.Add(new TestModels() { ID = 5, ParentID = 4, Text = "a5" });


    RadTreeView1.DataTextField = "Text";
    RadTreeView1.DataFieldID = "ID";
    RadTreeView1.DataFieldParentID = "ParentID";
    RadTreeView1.DataSource = models;
    RadTreeView1.DataBind();
}
```

Class

```
public class TestModels
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Please Set NULL in ParentID in place-of 0.**
Because It consider 0 as value. RadTreeView is not able to found any ID field which have 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
DataTable data= GetDataFromDatabase()
RadTreeView1.DataTextField = "TextFieldwhichyouwantshow";
RadTreeView1.DataFieldID = "IDFromdatabase";
RadTreeView1.DataFieldParentID = "ParentIDFromDatabase";
RadTreeView1.DataSource = data;
RadTreeView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Could You please give sample

Comment: see this- http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-data-binding-database.html